# Take IE6 Users to a specific page on first visit and only on home page

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I'm using PHP includes on a static website, I'm using the same header.php for all pages and changing things like page title etc using php.

For IE6 users I just on the home page I want them to be redirected to unsupported.php where they get prompted to upgrade their browser.

They get a text only style sheet and I feel that I need to explain why the site looks unstyled.

Can anyone provide an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just need some sort of flag to designate whether the user is on the home page or not, a variable with a simple boolean value would suffice:

```
$home = true;

if (isset($home) && $home === true) {
    echo 'You are on the home page';
    // do IE warning here
}
```

From there you could then say, check the browser user agent string. If it *is* IE 6 (I don’t know the user agent string off the top of my head) then you can set a cookie saying warning has been viewed and do a `header()` redirect. Then any time the IE 6-using visitor visits your website, check if the cookie’s set and just display the page as normal.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['ie_warned'])) {
    setcookie('ie_warned', true, strtotime('1 month'));
    header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
    header('Location: unsupported.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'll try the cookie one first and see how I get on.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could wrap something like this in your PHP-header.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script language="Javascript">
window.location = "http://www.site.com/unsupported.php";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Unless you have this on all pages , the individual pages are still accessable with IE6

Comment: OP only wants home page requests to be redirect; this would redirect *any* request.